# How do I use the manual exposure setting in the new Google Camera app?

Tags: exposure, camera-settings, manual-mode, android, apps

In April 2014, Google revamped its Android camera app. In the settings menu under "Advanced", there is just one option: *Manual exposure*. It defaults to off, but after turning in it on, I can't find any actual controls to manually adjust exposure parameters. I doubt my phone's camera module actually has a physically variable aperture, but I expected to see some way to adjust shutter speed and ISO — or at least to set an exposure value. But I don't see anything. How do I use this new feature?

Comment: No luck with the default app. This open source camera is the only way I have found: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sadly, the feature's name is misleading. In fact, I'd go so far as to say that it's *wrong*, if not an outright lie. **Turning this option on just enables you to use *exposure compensation* — it doesn't let you do anything actually "manual".**

If you enable this option, the `...` menu at the lower right of the screen gains a `+/-` icon, as typically indicates exposure value compensation. Selecting this allows you to choose compensation on a scale from -2 to +2. Exposure is still entirely automatic, and even with a value selected here will change automatically as lighting in the frame changes. **You can't use this to get a constant exposure from shot to shot, or set based on external metering, or anything else you would want to use actual manual exposure for.**

I don't understand why this is mislabeled, and I also don't understand why EV compensation isn't available by default. I guess it protects against newbies ruining their images by leaving it on accidentally, but there is an obvious indicator when a compensation value is selected, and EV compensation (with the same icon!) is common on pretty much all cameras at all price ranges. So, it's a mystery. And also something I'm reporting as a bug.

---

Note that the above applies to the Android 4.4 "Kit Kat" camera and to that app in 5.0 Lollipop. Lollipop *does* provide APIs allowing apps to have greater manual control, but the built-in camera doesn't take advantage of that, even with this option enabled.

Comment: Maybe today it's "manual" if you can control *anything* (not *everything*).